# Mongodb querie get peaks of timeseries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb with some sensor data in it. Each time the sensor is triggered the value increases by 1. Sometimes the sensor is being reset. Now I want to sum up the value of the sensor data to get the total value of a timeseries.

My data looks like this:

```
{
    value: 10
    timestamp: 1577836800
}, {
    value: 12
    timestamp: 1577836810
}, {
    value: 17 <== PEAK
    timestamp: 1577836820
}, {
    value: 2
    timestamp: 1577836830
}, {
    value: 7
    timestamp: 1577836840
}, {
    value: 10 <== PEAK
    timestamp: 1577836850
},{
    value: 1
    timestamp: 1577836860
}
```

My goal is to get all the values of the peaks (17 + 10), within a min and max timestamp, and sum them up (This could also be done manually afterwards). That would mean I have to sort them by timestamp and compare a value with the previous one to check which one is higher. I am new to mongo and don't know where to start. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Are you creating a new document per period? That would make the query very simple but if that isn't the case then we need to create a JavaScript function to found out what the periods (time serie) are.

Comment: Yes, I create a new object each period. So each object in the upper code is a new document. Sorry, I should have made that clear.

Comment: No worries, the challenge right now is that the starting value and the peak value combined with the periods are scattered throughout the collection. Are you using an edge device to insert the document or is your sensor doing this?

Comment: The data is written by a nodeJS Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mentioned in the comment regarding the usage of an edge device which makes it possible to assign the value to the proper period. Use the nodeJS service to figure out and which document it has to update because it make querying the collection much easier and faster.

You could use this format per document:

```
{
    "period" : {
        "start" : 1577836800,
        "end" : 1577836820
    },
    "values": [
        {
            "value": 10
            "timestamp": 1577836800
        }, 
        {
            "value": 12
            "timestamp": 1577836810
        }, 
        {
            "value": 17
            "timestamp": 1577836820
        }
    ]
}
```

As an example when the sensor provides the service with a new value. In this case the value 2, get the last document and compare this with the last value within values.

if the new value is less then the previous value, create a new document with the following information and of course don't forget to update the previous document with filling out the "periode.end" with the last value's timestamp.

```
{
    "period" : {
        "start" : 1577836830,
        "end" : null
    },
    "values": [
        {
            "value": 2
            "timestamp": 1577836830
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I wrote this JavaScript script to migrate from one collection, process the data into a new format based on the requirements and insert those into the new collection.

```
function createSensorObject(start, value){
    var doc = new Object();

    doc.period = new Object();
    doc.period["start"] = start;
    doc.period["end"] = null;

    doc.values = new Array();

    var valueObject = new Object();
    valueObject["value"] = value;
    valueObject["timestamp"] = start;

    doc.values.push(valueObject);
    return doc;
}

function pushNewValueIntoSensorObject(doc, value, timestamp){
    doc["period"]["end"] = timestamp;

    var valueObject = new Object();
    valueObject["value"] = value;
    valueObject["timestamp"] = timestamp;

    doc["values"].push(valueObject);
}

function closePeriodInSensorObject(doc) {
    doc["period"]["end"] = doc["period"]["start"];
}

// New collection cursor to insert new values.
var sensorNewCursor = db.sensor_new; 

// Using the aggregate pipeline to sort and using toArray to iterate through.
var sensorDocuments = db.sensor.aggregate([ { $sort: { "timestamp" : 1}}]).toArray();

// Temp array to store the new sensor objects.
var sensorObjectArray = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < sensorDocuments.length; i++) {
    // Working with the current document.
    var currentDocument = sensorDocuments[i];
    var value = currentDocument["value"];
    var timestamp = currentDocument["timestamp"];

    // Initially creating a new document.
    if(i === 0) {
        var sensorObject = createSensorObject(timestamp, value);

        // If there is only one document then we need to close the document.
        if(i === (sensorDocuments.Length - 1)) {
            closePeriodInSensorObject(sensorObject);
        }

        // Push into temp array.
        sensorObjectArray.push(sensorObject);
    }
    else{   
        // Get the previous value.
        var previousValue = sensorDocuments[i - 1]["value"];

        // Get the latest sensor object from the temp array.
        var sensorObject = sensorObjectArray[sensorObjectArray.length - 1];

        // When the new value is larger or equal to the previous value.
        if(value >= previousValue) {
            // Push the new value into the latest sensor object.
            pushNewValueIntoSensorObject(sensorObject, value, timestamp);
        }
        else {  
            // Create new sensor object.
            var sensorObject = createSensorObject(timestamp, value);
            sensorObjectArray.push(sensorObject);
        }
    }
}

print(`Inserting ${sensorObjectArray.length} objects into the db.sensor_new collection.`);

// Insert the whole array into the new collection
sensorNewCursor.insert(sensorObjectArray);
```

You can use the **load** function to call this js file from the mongoshell.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/

---

Take a look at the two screenshots.

[image: Original data]

[image: New data]

---

**Finally! The query**

You must use the aggregation pipeline to get the sum of the max value per periode.

First we need to unwind the values then $group with the $max to find our max value and then group again but without an $_id field to $sum the values.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$values"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "value": {
                $max: "$values.value"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": null,
            "total": {
                $sum: "$value"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The result of this query would be 28

```
[
    {
        "_id": null,
        "total": 28
    }
]
```

MongoPlayground according to the new document structure:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/WblN5QzPoeB

I really hope that this is working on your end, if it doesn't please comment. :)

Comment: That's a good idea, but currently I have the problem that the data is already in the Database. Best would be a query for now.

Comment: Then we would have to write a javascript function to migrate the data to a new collection because this is not possible with a query.